# Как увидеть код, который я делаю в интерактивной режиме MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо импортировать .csv файл с сервера SSH с помощью SQL запроса (*запрос нужен, чтобы потом его вшить в Python код)*.
В интерактивном режиме у меня все работает. Есть особенность, что при выборе импорта необходимо менять настройку **Encoding: utf-16**

Есть код, который вроде работает, но импортирует 0 строк:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/Копия data (003).csv'
INTO TABLE Data_1.data_123 
CHARACTER SET utf16
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY 'n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Тут все работает, но как мне вытащить код, который этот интерактив выполняет?[image: Вот скрин настройки импорта в интерактиве]

Comment: [The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html)

Comment: @Akina у меня в логах иероглифы, как быть?

Comment: Подобрать кодировку вьювера, в которой видны вменяемые символы. Впрочем, вряд ли текст запроса будет иероглифами...